# Formatting docbook indexterm

Tags: indexing, fonts, docbook

I am creating a manual and I use the index for listing the functions in alphabetical order. The functions are declared as follows

```
<itemizedlist>
    <listitem id="period">
        <indexterm><primary><varname>period</varname></primary></indexterm>
        <para>Constructor for <varname>period</varname></para>
        <para><varname>period(timestamptz, timestamptz, left_inc = true, right_inc = false): period</varname></para>
    </listitem>
    <listitem id="timestampset">
        <indexterm><primary><varname>timestampset</varname></primary></indexterm>
        <para>Constructor for <varname>timestampset</varname></para>
        <para><varname>timestampset(timestamptz[]): timestampset</varname></para>
    </listitem>
    [...]
</itemizedlist>
```

The problem is that the functions appear in the main text in `monospaced font` but this is not the case in the index despite the fact that the terms are enclosed into the `varname` element. Any idea how to achieve this ?

Comment: Is the output format PDF file or other? Do you use the default DocBook XSL Stylesheets (version?) Please, provide as many details as possible, because there are alot of possible solutions available, but there are some grade of uncertainty in your exact situation.

Comment: The problem is the same for PDF or HTML. I use the following command to produce e.g., the HTML format `xsltproc --stringparam html.stylesheet "docbook.css" --xinclude -o index.html /usr/share/xml/docbook/stylesheet/docbook-xsl/html/chunk.xsl mobilitydb-manual.xml` I use the default style sheets. The version information in the file is `$Id: chunk.xsl 9801 2013-09-06 19:23:43Z bobstayton $`

Comment: The point is that DocBook uses XSLT to produce any output result. You need to have some knowledge in XSLT to tweak this output. Do you have such knowledge (what xslt is and how it works)?

Comment: I have some knowledge about XSLT but I wondered whether there is a standard solution for this.

Comment: I guess it would be better to post here a snippet from the output you wondered, not only from the source.

Comment: The current output is composed of entries like `<dt id="ientry-idp1076">setPrecision, <a class="indexterm" href="ch04s05.html">Modification Functions</a></dt>` and probably the entry should honor the `<varname>` tag in DocBook as follows `<dt id="ientry-idp1076"><code class="varname">setPrecision</code>, <a class="indexterm" href="ch04s05.html">Modification Functions</a></dt>
`